# Realm, RxJava, asObservable() and doOnUnsubscribe()

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, realm

In my Android projects, I use [realm](http://realm.io) as my data storage engine. I love it! 
I also use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) because it makes "threading" so much easier, and I really like the whole "reactive mindset". I love it!

I use an MVP pattern + some "Clean architecture" ideas to build my apps.

My `Interactors` are the only ones who know about `Realm`. I expose data with the help of Observable, like this:

```
@Override
public Observable<City> getHomeTown() {
    final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm.where(City.class).equalTo("name", "Cluj-Napoca").findAllAsync().asObservable()
            .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    realm.close();
                }
            })
            .compose(new NullIfNoRealmObject<City>());
}
```

The problem is my `doOnUnsubscribe` side-effect gets called before `Realm` can do its thing, handling the exposed observable:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:344)
at io.realm.RealmResults.removeChangeListener(RealmResults.java:818)
at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$3$2.call(RealmObservableFactory.java:137)
at rx.subscriptions.BooleanSubscription.unsubscribe(BooleanSubscription.java:71)
at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribeFromAll(SubscriptionList.java:124)
at rx.internal.util.SubscriptionList.unsubscribe(SubscriptionList.java:113)
at rx.Subscriber.unsubscribe(Subscriber.java:98)
at rx.subscriptions.CompositeSubscription.unsubscribeFromAll(CompositeSubscription.java:150)
at rx.subscriptions.CompositeSubscription.unsubscribe(CompositeSubscription.java:139)
at ro.tudorluca.realm.sandbox.city.CityPresenter.onDestroy(CityPresenter.java:62)
at ro.tudorluca.realm.sandbox.city.CityActivity.onDestroy(CityActivity.java:35)
```

I created a [sandbox](https://github.com/lucamtudor/Realm-RxJava-Sandbox) project for this use case.

I really like using Realm+RxJava, but I can't seem to find a clean solution to `close` the Realm instance when I `unsubscribe` (I usually unsubscribe when the activity gets destroyed). Any ideas?

**Edit 1**: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2357
**Edit 2**: thanks to the very active realm team, there is already a [pull request](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

21 hours later and this is what I came up with:

```
@Override
public Observable<City> getHomeTown() {
    return getManagedRealm()
            .concatMap(new Func1<Realm, Observable<City>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<City> call(Realm realm) {
                    return realm.where(City.class).equalTo("name", "Cluj-Napoca").findAllAsync().asObservable()
                            .compose(new NullIfNoRealmObject<City>());
                }
            });
}

private static Observable<Realm> getManagedRealm() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Realm>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Realm> subscriber) {
            final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }));
            subscriber.onNext(realm);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried something like this before posting the question on stackoverflow, but my mistake was using `flatMap()`, instead of `concatMap()`.

Unlike `flatMap()`,`concatMap()` will keep the order of the emissions which, in my case, means that my `Action0 -> realm.close()` will be the last action being called after unsubscribing from the stream, after Realm's `Action0 -> results.removeChangeListener(listener)` which was causing the problem.

A full example can be found on [github](https://github.com/lucamtudor/Realm-RxJava-Sandbox).

**Edit**: thanks to the very active realm team, there is already a [pull request](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2364) to fix this issue.

Comment: Consider wrapping Realm via Observable#using, this will simplify your getManagedRealm() method: http://pastebin.com/CrzryvCq

Comment: I try your solution and I faced problem: too many open in realm file

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that only the *Interactor* "knows" about the Realm framework I would say not to even return a managed Realm object, instead return an unmanaged copy of the results using `copyFromRealm`. That way you don't have to care about the Realm instance being open or closed in the *Presenter*.

At the same time I would let the *Presenter* chose wether the call should be done asynchronous or not since `RxJava` does that pretty cool and easy and you won't have issues calling the *Interactor* load method within another thread(which can be avoided using Loopers but why overcomplicate the situation if you can make it simpler :P ).

So I would go for:

```
Override
public Observable<City> getHomeTown() {
    final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    City city = realm.where(City.class).equalTo("name", "Cluj-Napoca").findFirst();

    // make sure we don't send back Realm stuff, this is a deep copy that will copy all referenced objects (as the method doc says)
    City cityUnmanaged = realm.copyFromRealm(city);

    // safe to close the realm instance now
    realm.close();

    return Observable.just(cityUnmanaged);
}
```

I am curious to see more options :).

Comment: Returning an Observable<City>, my Interactor fully embraces the "reactive mindset". When you execute the query, the Interactor will return a stream that will push the data when it's ready and available. When new data is available, the returned stream is ready to push you that data. In my case, I will get an updated city each time someone else pushed changes to realm. "Auto-refresh" is a core feature of Realm, and a very nice one.

Comment: Also, copyFromRealm() is ok for my demo, because my objects are small with no relationships. But in real life, I have a complex graph of objects and I really don't want to load them all into memory. "Lazy+no-copy data" is another core feature of Realm that you should take full advantage of whenever you can.

Comment: Realm has a "threading" limitation and you cannot use RxJava to handle multi-threaded queries. There is a good example project you can explore for more gotchas: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/rxJavaExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/rxjava/gotchas/GotchasActivity.java

Comment: You're right, my example doesn't work as a stream that sends new changes back to the observer but that is why I can use synchronous realm query and close it right away. Also there is a copyFromRealm method that has a flag that we can use to specify the depth of the deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

As per me, one of the major thing to look after in a good architecture is modularity. All the major modules(or libraries) should be isolated from rest of the code. Since Realm, RealmObject or RealmResult can not be passed across threads, it is even more important to make Realm & Realm related operations isolated from rest of the code.

Keeping this philosophy in mind, I came up with the following approach.

For every jsonModel class, we create a realmModel class and a DAO (Data Access Object) class. Idea here is that other than DAO class none of the class must know or access realmModel or Realm entities. DAO class takes jsonModel, converts it to realmModel, performs read/write/edit/remove operations & for read operations DAO converts resulted realmModel to jsonModel and returns them.

This way it is easy to maintain Realm, avoid all thread related issues, easy to test and debug.

Here is an article about Realm best practices with a good architechture https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f

Also a sample project demonstrating Integration of Realm on Android with MVP(Model View Presenter), RxJava, Retrofit, Dagger, Annotations & Testing. https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test